# How to Use NavBar in all pages of the website without messing links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

My Nav bar code :-

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have seen an question related to this already and the solution is :-

```js
$('#addnav').load.(navBar.html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The solution is by using `jquery` `load` function

We are placing navBar code in a `html` file and loading it through jquery where ever required

But the problem is about links how do I change them if I'm in the `/location/example.html` then how the home page is going to be directed

I cannot place this question as a comment in that post because my reputation haven't been reached 50 when I have asked this question

More detailed explain :-

let my home page location be `/index.html`
now, another page location be `/dir1/dir2/xyz.html`

`navBar.html` is palced inside `xyz.html` and if I click `home` then will it direct me to `/index.html`

Comment: it is ok as a question and not a comment too...

Comment: 2 possible solutions: Use absolute URLs or save a base-url and attach it to the `href`

Comment: Do you have any home.html?

Comment: What happens if someone has JavaScript disabled? Plus this might cause SEO related issues. You are better off doing this in PHP.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I mentioned because sometime some may find the question as already asked and tag it as already answered

Comment: @WizardCoder I am making this in github pages so how do I have `php` run in it

Comment: @ChandanKumarThakur home.html is not a matter I am asking that how to be directed from one page to another page

Comment: @DevelopersWork, as far as I know you can't use PHP in github pages. :(

Comment: Sorry if this is a really stupid response, but can you just do `\about.html`. That will always take you to the correct URL regardless of where you are on the website. I am no familiar with github pages, so I could be missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I undestand your problem but try to use "/" to make it a root-relative URL.

```
<li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working. I will add some extra details to question so that you may understand